# test that method was called inside another method with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, rspec-rails

I have to write a spec for the following method:

```
def track_event
  tracker = set_tracker
  category = define_event_category
  tracker.event(category: category, action: name, label: properties['short_name'], value: properties['paid'])
end
```

To be specific I have to to check if method `event` is called on the variable `tracker` when `track_event` is called. I tried to do it like this:

```
describe '#track_event' do
  it 'should call event method' do
    expect(tracker).to receive(:event)
  end
end
```

and got an error `undefined local variable or method 'tracker'`. What do I do wrong?

Comment: Yes, because you didn't define `tracker` before calling it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot access `tracker` because it is a local variable.

You could stub your `set_tracker` method instead and return an [instance double](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-7/docs/verifying-doubles/using-an-instance-double):

```
describe '#track_event' do
  let(:tracker_double) { instance_double(Tracker) }

  it 'should call event method' do
    allow(foo).to receive(:set_tracker).and_return(tracker_double)
    expect(tracker_double).to receive(:event)
    foo.track_event
  end
end
```

`foo` is your test subject.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming in your rspecs, `subject` is the instance of class where `track_event` method is defined, you can stub the value returned from `set_tracker` to an object defined by you and then check if the method `event` is called on that `tracker` object.

```
 describe '#track_event' do
   # Build a tracker object
   let(:tracker) { <Whatever type of object you expect as a tracker> }

   # Stub the output of `set_tracker`
   before { allow(subject).to receive(:set_tracker) { tracker } }

   it 'should call event method' do
     expect(tracker).to receive(:event)
   end

   after { subject.track_event }
 end
```

I would recommend verifying the arguments too with the method call.